# Формулировка ответа

Tags: python

Даны два целых числа. Программа должна вывести число 1, если первое число больше второго, число 2, если второе больше первого, или число 0, если они равны.
Вводятся два целых числа, не превышающие 2∗109 по абсолютному значению.
Выведите ответ на задачу.

Моё решение:

```
n=int(input())
m=int(input())
n<=2*10**9
m<=2*10**9
if n>m:
    print(1)
if n<m:
    print(2)
else:
    print(0)
```

Программа говорит, что ответ выдаётся в неверном формате. Пробовал ставить кавычки, ставить `int` в начало ответа, но бесполезно.

Что не так?

Comment: если n>m вы выведете 10

Comment: сделайте `elif`

Comment: А что вы хотели сказать вот этим? n<=2*10**9

Answer (score 0):

Вот мое решение:

```
while True:
    n=int(input('Введите 1 число '))
    m=int(input('Введите 2 число '))
    x = n<=2*10**9
    y = m<=2*10**9

    # Если хотя бы одно из чисел не подходит под условие
    if not x or not y:
        continue

    if n>m:
        print(1)
        break
    if n<m:
        print(2)
        break
    if n==m:
        print(0)
        break
```

Вам нужно сделать проверку ввелось ли число не больше 2∗109
Это делает цикл While.
x и y значения логического типа(bool). Они могут принимать только True или False.
Если хотя бы одно значение False то просят ввести число заново

```
Введите 1 число 9999999999999999999999
Введите 2 число 9999999999999999999999
Введите 1 число 99999
Введите 2 число 99999
0
```

Comment: Я бы провел код-ревью: **1)** вместо `if x==True and y==True:` можно проще: `if x and y:`. **2)** `n=int(...` и `m=int(...` можно не дублировать если занести в цикл и немного условия поменять, например при `if not x or not y: continue`

Comment: Немного перемудрили, подправил. Кст, теперь `break` там не нужны ;)